# this is my add to cart code when i click on add to cart it is giving me extra empty row which i don't want

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

This is the code of table were user gives input:

```
<table id = "form">
<td> <select name = "Colour" id ="Colour">
<option>blue</option>
<option>pink</option>
<option>orange</option>
<option>red</option>
</select></td>
<td> <select name = "Organize" id ="Organize">
<option>preethi enterprise</option>
<option>prasanna enterprise</option>
</select></td>
<td> <input type ="text" name ="Company" id ="Company"></td>
<td><input type ="text" name ="Subdivision" id ="Subdivision"></td>
</table>
```

This is  the code of table when user click on add to cart, it should store in this table:

```
<table id="cart">
<tr>
<th><label>Colour</label></th>
<th><label>Organize</label></th>
<th><label>Company</label></th>
<th><label>Subdivision</label></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type = "text" readonly></td>
<td><input type = "text" readonly></td>
<td><input type = "text" readonly></td>
<td><input type = "text" readonly></td>
<td><input type ="button" value ="remove" onclick="remove(this)"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the code for addTo():

```
function addTo() { // to add rows and copy value to cart
  var table = document.getElementById('cart');
  var new_row = table.rows[1].cloneNode(true); // clones the first row 
  var len = table.rows.length;  // number of rows in table
  var inp1 = new_row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp1.value = document.getElementById("Colour").value;
  var inp2 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp2.value = document.getElementById("Organize").value;
  var inp3 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp3.value =  document.getElementById("Company").value;
  var inp4 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp4.value = document.getElementById("Subdivision").value;
  table.appendChild(new_row);
}
```

When I try to add a new row to the table one empty row is added at first.

The row should get added only when the users clicks on add to cart with values.

Also, an error message should be displayed when an user tries to add empty rows.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: it would be easy to solve your problem if you share your code with plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: You cold specify which fields are required

Comment: We need more code for solve your problem, Kindly provide pls.

Comment: i stored the code in this link https://plnkr.co/edit/qjswaRpKKPoRDmKM

Comment: u can see empty row is getting added for first time i don't want that empty row to add.Please help me for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `hide` first row of your table .Then , whenever `addTo()` is call you can unhide that row to make clone of it and after cloning hide it again or else other way would be creating the entire `row` again inside your js code .

**Demo code** :

```js
function addTo() { // to add rows and copy value to cart
  if ((document.getElementById("Colour").value === "") || (document.getElementById("Organize").value === "") || (document.getElementById("Company").value === "") || (document.getElementById("Subdivision").value === "")) {
    //display error message
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "All fields required";


  } else {
    //unhiding  1st row to cloned it
    document.getElementById('show').style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
    var table = document.getElementById('cart');

    var new_row = table.rows[1].cloneNode(true); // clones the first row 
    var len = table.rows.length; // number of rows in table
    var inp1 = new_row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.value = document.getElementById("Colour").value;
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.value = document.getElementById("Organize").value;
    var inp3 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp3.value = document.getElementById("Company").value;
    var inp4 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp4.value = document.getElementById("Subdivision").value;
    table.appendChild(new_row);
    //hide again after cloning 
    document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  color: #f44336;
}
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>
<table id="form">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="Colour" id="Colour" required>
        <option>blue</option>
        <option>pink</option>
        <option>orange</option>
        <option>red</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="Organize" id="Organize" required>
        <option>preethi enterprise</option>
        <option>prasanna enterprise</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="Company" id="Company" required></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Subdivision" id="Subdivision" required></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="addTo()">Add to Cart</button>


<table id="cart">
  <tr>
    <th><label>Colour</label></th>
    <th><label>Organize</label></th>
    <th><label>Company</label></th>
    <th><label>Subdivision</label></th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="show" style="display:none;">
    <td><input type="text" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="remove" onclick="remove(this)" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please help me for this above code were error test is displaying i need a popup box to display so how can i achieve that please help me for this